Get names from a list of ids with separator
I have a table to store country ids
SEQ_ID  CountryID
  1     1|2
  2      1
  3     1|2|3

My country table
CountryID   Name
   1        USA
   2        UK
   3        India

How to get result as below
SEQ_ID      Country
  1          USA|UK
  2          USA
  3          USA|UK|INDIA


Kindly you can check this recent question out

First of all, that's  wrong design which you should take care off first

@Rahul agree, but need to use it for nw since its a legacy system.
